# need help for python command line argument using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I need some help regarding using argparse. What I want to achieve is that I need to pass in only one argument, it could be one of the followings: `--k, --r, --b, --p,(ignore the rest)`. If the argument count is not 1, print "usage" information and quit. Also the program needs to know which flag is passed in in order to create corresponding object. I tried several times but I doesn't work, can anyone give me a hint on this? Thanks.

Comment: "I tried several times but I doesn't work": Can you post what you tried and explain what exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to use to accomplish that is a [mutually exclusive group](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-k', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('-r', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('-b', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('-p', action='store_true')
parser.parse_args()
```

As it can be seen in the example below, only one option in a mutually exclusive group is allowed at the same time:

```
$ python test.py -k -r -b -p
usage: test.py [-h] [-k | -r | -b | -p]
test.py: error: argument -r: not allowed with argument -k
```

To check which flag was passed, you just need to look at the `argparse.Namespace` object returned by `parse_args` method (the flag passed will be set to `True`).

Comment: Good job! It seems that I'm totally on the wrong track, thx for the sample!

Answer (score 3):

How about not using `argparse` at all?  It doesn't seem really necessary.

```
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print_usage()
arg = sys.argv[1]
if arg not in ["--k", "--r", "--b", "--p"]:
    print_usage()
# Do whatever you want with arg
```